# How to close thread when firefox closes

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom

I have a extension that uses multithreading using worker thread as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_workers_in_extensions) . 
Whenever worker thread returns value to main thread, I am updating UI and I am starting that thread again because I want to continuously execute that operation. I cannot use setInterval because inside thread is a call to C++ XPCOM component function which does socket recv blocking call and that reception may not be periodic.

Now when I close firefox, firefox window is closed but the firefox process keeps on running and consuming 99% CPU. So I always need to close that process forcefully.

How to close that process completely. 
Extension is in overlay like this

```
<overlay id="helloworldOverlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<statusbar id="status-bar">
.
.
.
</statusbar>
</overlay>
```

Comment: what is the thread doing? Why don't you put the setInterval in the main thread?

Comment: I cannot use setInterval because inside thread is a call to C++ XPCOM component function which does socket recv blocking call and that reception may not be periodic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `terminate` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Worker#Methods

Comment: terminate.. where do I call it, is it present in javascript, or any service?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Worker it's a worker method (like postMessage)